# How to implement a delegator using ExtJS 4.1

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, delegation

I am new to javascript, but I've been hired to give maintenance to an application which is developed in Sencha ExtJS 4. One of the modules I've been asked to modify, is of a component in which I show a tooltip whenever I hover over it. This component can be present in more than one view, it is something like "Customer Details" that is present in many screens of the application. If I hover over this data, I need to show a tooltip, this tooltip shows information retrieved by server (REST). I implemented some logic, but this logic involves the use of many listeners in each of the components that will show the information. For instance, I added a listener in all of the views that requires showing the tooltip:

```
this.listeners = {
                boxready: {
                    fn: this.onAfterRender,
                    scope: this
                }
```

And I had to implement this method for every view as well, which is a mess and, for sure, a very bad practice:

```
/**
     * This method is executed after panels are rendered in order to set ToolTip listeners on
     * users and workgroups.
     * 
     * @param {Object} scope
     */
    onAfterRender: function(scope) {

    Ext.defer(function() {

        var usElements = Ext.get(Ext.query('.usertooltip', scope.el.dom));
        usElements.on({
            click: function (e) {
                var item = Ext.get(e.target);

                if (Ext.isEmpty(item.dom.innerHTML.trim())) {
                    item.removeCls('usertooltip');
                    return;
                }

                if (item.hasCls('usertooltip-clicked')) {
                    return;
                }

                item.addCls('usertooltip-clicked');
                var user = item.getAttribute('data-info');

                UserInfo.getUserInfo(user, false);
                if (UserInfo.errorResponse) {
                    UserInfo.getWGroupInfo(user);
                }
                UserInfo.displayToolTip(this);
            }
        });

        var wgElements = Ext.get(Ext.query('.wgtooltip', scope.el.dom));
        wgElements.on({
            click : function (e) {
                var item = Ext.get(e.target);

                if (Ext.isEmpty(item.dom.innerHTML.trim())) {
                    item.removeCls('wgtooltip');
                    return;
                }

                if (item.hasCls('wgtooltip-clicked')) {
                    return;
                }

                item.addCls('wgtooltip-clicked');
                var wgroup = item.getattribute('data-info');

                WGroupInfo.getWGroupInfo(wgroup, false);
                if (UserInfo.errorResponse) {
                    WGroupInfo.getUserInfo(wgroup);
                }
                WGroupInfo.displayToolTip(this);
            }
        });

    }, 1000, this);
},
```

What I do is simply detect if the item is selected based a css class, if so, I handle the events and proceed with logic. But I've been doing some research and I think this can be achieved using a "delegator" but I am not sure how to implement this for my scenario.

What I've been thinking of, so far is to create a "js" class which have a method like an "observer" and whenever listen to someone asking for this tooltip functionality, delegate it to the executing object. But since I am new to javascript and this Sencha ExtJS, my tries have been frustrated. If someone can help me I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to declare a plugin:

```
Ext.define('TipPlugin', {
    alias: 'plugin.tip',

    init: function(c) {
        c.on('boxready', this.onBoxReady, this);
    },

    onBoxReady: function(c) {
        var els = this.el.select('.usertooltip');
        // Do stuff!
    }
});

var c = new Ext.Component({
    plugins: ['tip']
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried with the plugin but no succeed, as mentioned I am very noob in js, but I solved the problem by using a mixin. Thanks for your support, I appreciate it.